# Aquamacs/Emacs Pane Auto-disposition

Tags: emacs, panel, startup, aquamacs

I'm using Aquamacs since few weeks and I'm trying to find good customizations.
First, I just wanted my aquamacs to look like this on starting :

[image]

I mean on the left, my source code. and on the right a shell pane (started with C-X 3 + M-X shell).

I've done some search on emacs/aquamacs forums, and in stackOverflow too. But I'm still blocked on this.
Thanks.
:)

Comment: I really think people shouldn't be voting to close if they can't be bothered to comment a remedy, that note aside, perhaps this belongs on http://superuser.com - but, since the solution will require elisp I think it's fair to say that it's programming related enough for SO.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

HEre is the stuff !!

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;;           C programming stuff

;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Hungry delete is nice since we use spaces instead of tabs.
(setq c-hungry-delete-key t)

;; Let emacs insert newlines automatically whenever it can.
(setq c-auto-newline 1)

;; Set the K&R indentation style when starting C-mode.

(add-hook 'c-mode-hook

```
      '(lambda ()
         (c-set-style "k&r")
         (auto-fill-mode 1)
         ))
```

Answer (score 2):

If all you need is to split the window and open the shell in the newly created window, you should be able to add this:

```
(split-window-horizontally nil)
(other-window 1)
(shell nil)
(other-window 1) ;; return you to the original window.
```

to the end of your `.emacs` or `.emacs.d/init.el` depending on how you initialise emacs.

Alternatively, make it a separate function, and bind to a key command. (add these to `.emacs` instead of the above code.)

e.g.

```
(defun split-window-for-shell ()
  "Split the current window and open a shell in the new window."
  (interactive)
    (split-window-horizontally nil)
    (other-window 1)
    (shell nil)
    (other-window 1) ;; return you to the original window.
  )
```

And bind with

```
(global-set-key (kbd "C-|") split-window-for-shell)
```

So you can use it when you want, and not just at startup.

(It will always show the same instance of shell.)

Comment: Wow! thank you very munch! it works exactly as it is supposed to!!

Comment: also, I wanted to enable c-hungry-delete mode at starting. But it's not working when i put : (c-toggle-hungry-delete 1) on my init.el. I got an error like : "Symbol's function definition is void: c-toggle-hungry-delete" do you know what's going on ? :)

Comment: My Emacs doesn't have hungry-delete mode, I don't know why (I can see that it's in the Emacs manual.) - But even Emacs Help, aprops 'hungry' shows no results, odd.  -- Anyway, Does hungry delete work for you usually?

Comment: Yes it does when i open a c file. I guess c-mode starts and In a menu "c" then toggles. I can enable "Hungry-delete".

Comment: Ok, there's no `c-toggle-hungry-delete` only, `c-toggle-hungry-state` ... I generally use something like `M-x` name[TAB] to find the correct identifier.

Comment: humm..  c-toggle-hungry state is only available when C-mode is enabled. When i tried "(c-toggle-hungry-state 1)", emacs failed to load. do you have an idea ? like (require c-mode)\n(c-toggle-hungry-state 1)

Comment: HEre is the stuff !! 
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;
;;    C programming stuff
;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;;

;; Hungry delete is nice since we use spaces instead of tabs.
(setq c-hungry-delete-key t) 

;; Let emacs insert newlines automatically whenever it can.
(setq c-auto-newline 1)

;; Set the K&R indentation style when starting C-mode.
(add-hook 'c-mode-hook
          '(lambda ()
             (c-set-style "k&r")
             (auto-fill-mode 1)
             ))